# Bug in Stack Overflow Careers "job" button

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, stack-exchange-button

There is a bug in the Careers button for redirecting to the job page:

```
<i data-jobid="77870"></i>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = '//careers.stackoverflow.com/mvcjs/apply.js?mode=Internal;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

There is a **'** missing after `...y.js?mode=Internal` --> `...y.js?mode=Internal';`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oops!

This has been fixed, thanks for the heads up.

Love it when our users not only report a bug, but also send us a fix <3

Comment: Admit it, you planted the bug there just so you can fix it and gain tons of repz! ;)